# stuck with data conversion SSIS

Tags: ssis

I'm stuck with a conversion problem...or atleast at datatype problem.
Trying to read a csv-file and update a SQL-database with its content.
The column I have problems with have numbers like 64,51 (at most 3 digits with 2 decimals).

In the database I have set the datatype as decimal(3,2) and in the flat file Connection manager I have set it as decimal(DT_DECIAL) with the scale of 2.
Along the flow I do a Derived column, merging two columns into one and then convert the new column.

Looking in the advanced editor of the OLE DB-destination I can see that in the Input Columns the column is set as DT_DECIMAL, but in the External column its set as a DT_NUMERIC.
How do I change that?
I can change the properties but every time it reverts back to numeric when I press OK.

The errormessage says: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type."

Thanks for all tips on this!

Comment: Are you inspecting the rows in the flow with data viewer?  Increase the scale in your database for testing purposed from decimal(3,2) to decimal(7,5).   I suspect the localeid of the file connection manager may need to be adjusted.

Comment: @vhoang that worked, somehow its 5 decimals when its stored in the database.
Like "64.51000", but how do I loose the trailing zeros?
Threw in a DataConversion and on datatype I use Decimal and at scale I have 2, and it works fine. Dont know why I need to convert when I have configured the properties of the column...well well...as long as it works.

Comment: With decimal(3,2), inserting in 46.5123 will get truncated, inserting in 1046.51 will fail with overflow.   There's probably something greater than 999.99 in the table, perhaps written as 1234,5 for some reason.    from what you're describing decimal(7,2) will dump the zeros and should still accept the data.